# Dividend paying with Erc20Votes

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin, staking, voting

I want to implement dividends in my platform working with an erc20votes token from Openzeppelin. The platform works with holders delegating their balance as votes to a representative. The elected representative perform some work and portion of their reward should be returned back to the voters as dividends.

When trying to implement that I have met the following problems. The balance of the voters at some past moments or intervals needs to be known, but:

1. Snapshots allow front running the snapshot itself or the submission of new work.
2. Erc20Votes does not track the balance of the users but only the change of the delegated votes. So if 2 or more people delegate to the same person I will only know the change in the total number of votes for the delegate but not the change in the individual balance of the voters.
3. Delegating each user's balance to themselves also does not seem like a solution since it contradicts the logic of delegating to a representative.

Can anyone help me with that? Is there an approach to implement this mechanism?